# PLSR: trait vs spectroscopic data gives very low R2 on plsr model in R

Tags: r, regression, modeling, accuracy, partial-least-squares

[here is the sample data.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o2bDVWuSVnRErKqy8kKQa0ONP4cf34nc2eRBX_X-gSQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I have spectroscopy data as X-variables (from X1 to X80) and corresponding Y variable.
I need to run plsr model in R using "pls" package. There are two sheets. In one X-variables are raw (without any pre-processing). and in other sheet X-variables are vector-normalized

Here, what I have done.

```
library(pls)
data1 <- read.csv("spectra.csv", header = TRUE)

# dividing data into training and testing
index = sample(1:nrow(data1), size = 0.6*nrow(data1))
cal.data = data1[index,]
val.data = data1[-index,]

model1 <- plsr(Y ~., data = cal.data, scale = TRUE, ncomp = 15, validation = "LOO")

summary(model1)
Data:   X dimension: 51 48 
    Y dimension: 51 1
Fit method: kernelpls
Number of components considered: 15

VALIDATION: RMSEP
Cross-validated using 51 leave-one-out segments.
       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps
CV         9.832     10.07    10.37    11.04    11.36    11.77    12.26
adjCV      9.832     10.07    10.36    11.03    11.33    11.76    12.22
       7 comps  8 comps  9 comps  10 comps  11 comps  12 comps  13 comps
CV      11.92    13.54    14.22    15.38     15.58     15.60     16.01
adjCV   11.88    13.50    14.15    15.28     15.47     15.48     15.87
       14 comps  15 comps
CV       16.73    16.62
adjCV    16.57    16.47

TRAINING: % variance explained
   1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps  6 comps  7 comps
X   95.6513   98.402   99.161    99.71    99.80    99.85    99.88
Y   0.6143    4.903    7.394    10.53    18.13    31.04    38.64
   8 comps  9 comps  10 comps  11 comps  12 comps  13 comps  14 comps
X   99.94    99.95     99.96     99.96     99.96     99.97     99.97
Y   42.21    55.37     66.60     72.20     78.77     85.49     90.23
   15 comps
X   99.97
Y   92.33
```

Currrently I am facing major two issues..

1. from this result of plsr model, I am able to determine no. of components as RMSEP increasing with no. of components.
2. R2 value is very very low (i.e., <0.1)

What can be done to determine PLS component and how can I increase model accuracy..

I have tried pls model on vector-normalised data as well but getting nearly same result.